# Remote query with combobox on Enter hit

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a combobox which has a remote store. When a user writes down three or more letters, I see a server request, but I want to fire this request when the user hits Enter button. At this moment my combo has these properties:

```
forceSelection:true,
enableKeyEvents:true,
listeners:{
    keyup:function(){ // I prevent "normal" server requests in this manner
        return false;
    },
    keydown:function(){
        return false;
    },
    keypress: function() {
        return false;
    },
    specialkey:function(a,b,c){
        if(b.keyCode==13){
            // But at this moment I want to make a request          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set 'minChars' to an extremely high value, to disable value selection on typing.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-minChars

Then expand the combobox selection on enter key:

```
forceSelection:true,
enableKeyEvents:true,
// show value selection after typing 999 chars
minChars: 999,
// set triggerAction to 'query' to show only filtered results after pressing enter
triggerAction: 'query',
listeners: {
    specialkey: function (combobox, e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            combobox.expand();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!